# Python 3.5.2 Non-Ascii Character Output

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, non-ascii-characters

I'm running Python 3.5.2 and am trying to do some basic stuff with unicode and UTF-8. I'm currently just trying to output non-ASCII characters and am unable to do so. For example, this:

```
ddd = '\u0144'
print(ddd)
```

gives me a Unicode encode error, telling me that the character maps to undefined. From what I understand of unicode in Python 3.5.2, mapping should happen automatically. I tried putting `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` before the code and various combinations of `.decode` and `.encode` as well, but to no avail.

Comment: the problem is that, the console that you are using doesn't have that unicode mapped to anything (the console doesn't support unicode.). Try writing that to a file and see

Comment: It works for me – Mac OSX 10.7.5: `ń`. It must be something in your local system.

Comment: Do you have your terminal set to use UTF-8?

Comment: The Windows Command Prompt can't Unicode properly. You can use [win-unicode-console](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/win_unicode_console) to try to work around it.

Answer (score 1):

PM 2Ring, typing in `chcp 65001` in command prompt did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Note there are longstanding bugs in conhost that will make print/input fail (produce inconsistent results or hang up) for non-ASCII characters in code page 65001. This is not a panacea.